# JavaScript immediate function invocation - why are parenthesis needed around the function?

Tags: javascript

Why does a function declaration need to be wrapped in parentheses to be immediately invoked?  I'm curious as to how the interpreter reads the immediately invoked function when wrapped in parentheses.

I.e.

Why must I do this...

```
(function() { 
   // Logic 
 })();
```

and not this...

```
function() { 
   // Logic 
 }();
```

Comment: The second is OK where an expression is allowed, e.g. `var x = function(){return 'foo'}();`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When a function is wrapped in parenthesis it's parsed as an expression - a function expression. Otherwise without them it's parsed as a function *declaration*. A function declaration requires a name which it sees you have not given it, which in turn causes a syntax error. Moreover, you can't apply `()` inline to a function declaration in order to call it. The empty parenthesis is a syntax error, but a non-empty parenthesis is an expression which will be evaluated separately from the function.

Comment: `function foo(){}(bar);` is valid though, but it does not do what one might intend.

Comment: Wonderful answer that makes total sense, thank you.

Comment: @FelixKling, what would your example do?

Comment: @contactmatt: It would define a function `foo` and then *evaluate* the expression inside the parenthesis. In `(bar)`, the parenthesis are the grouping operator (as in `(5 + 3) * 2`), they are not calling parenthesis.